# retrieving data from database using ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to retrieve the datas from db in accordance with the range of calender using ajax and jquery.
I cant able to pass the id to calender.php. ie d1 and d2 from the calender.

```
<form action="" method="post" class="getcalender" id="form1">
From : <input type="text" name="d1" id="d1" class="tcal"/>
 To: <input type="text" name="d2" id="d2" class="tcal" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="tcal" id="submit"  />
</form>
<div id="data_result"  border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
</div>
    $('#submit').click(function(){
    $.ajax({

            url:"getcalender.php",
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(output_string){
                    $("#data_result").html(output_string);
                } 
            }); 

});
```

my calendar.php is here.here d1(date1) and (date2) d2 values is not getting.

```
<?php
    $d1 = $_POST["d1"];
    $d2 =$_POST["d2"];
     $sql ="select a.`id` 'User ID', a.`username` 'Name of User', MAX(b.login_timestamp) 'Last Logged in date',count(*) 'Total No. of logins',count(*)/7 'Avg no. of Logins /day' from users a left join `client_access_log` b   on b.unique_id=a.unique_id  where `login_timestamp` BETWEEN '{$d1}' and '{$d2}' GROUP BY a.`id`";

 $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(!$query)
{
    mysql_close();
    echo json_encode("There was an error running the query: " . mysql_error());
}
elseif(mysql_num_rows($query)==0)
{
    mysql_close();
    echo json_encode("No Login");
    exit;
}
else
{
    $header = false;
    $output_string = "";
    $output_string .=  "<table border='1'>\n"; 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        if(!$header)
        {
            $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
            foreach($row as $header => $value)
            {
                $output_string .= "<th>{$header}</th>\n";
            }
            $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
        }
        $output_string .= "<tr>\n";
        foreach($row as $value)
        {
            $output_string .= "<th>{$value}</th>\n";
        }
        $output_string .= "</tr>\n";
    }
    $output_string .= "</table>\n";
}
    mysql_close();
echo json_encode($output_string);
    ?>
```

Comment: you can get calendar value in the ajax code as like this - `$('#d1').val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending values currently in ajax call.
You need to pass values using `data` attribute of ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({

            url:"getcalender.php",
            type:'POST',
            data: {
                   d1:$('#d1').val(),
                   d2:$('#d2').val()
                  }
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(output_string){
                    $("#data_result").html(output_string);
                } 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method :-

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
var postData = $(this).serializeArray();//get you form data in a variable
$.ajax({

        url:"getcalender.php",
        date : postData 
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_string){
                $("#data_result").html(output_string);
            } 
        }); 

});
```

Check below lilnk http://developerhints.com/ajax-form-submit-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id through the query string. Inside your php you will retrieve the value and use it as you wish.

use $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to get query values.

your url should looks like this: getcalender.php?d1=value1&d2=value2

The function parse_str automatically transforms all query parameters into corresponding PHP variables. For example from the following URL:

```
getcalender.php?d1=1&d2=2
```

this code:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

will automatically create variables $d1 and $d2 with values 1 and 2 which you can then use in your code.